# Would questions on keeping a colony of ants be on topic here?

Tags: discussion, scope

Okay, where is the boundary drawn between animal care requirement questions on [Biology](https://biology.stackexchange.com/) (like [How should I feed and keep an ant queen?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/19582/how-should-i-feed-and-keep-an-ant-queen)) and this site? Is there some overlap? I know some questions (identification, for instance) are on topic on both Gardening and Biology. Is that the case with animal care questions on Pets?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, as they relate to 'pet' ants, like an [ant farm (formicarium)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formicarium) in a home.  The question on biology [How should I feed and keep an ant queen?](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/1958) focuses around a captured wild individual so that **Might** be out of scope.  A purchased ant farm with domesticated ants would definitely be in scope.

As a site we have not addressed the question; of questions about captured wild life being domesticated by the person who captured them, given the responses on the very few questions that lightly touch around the subject I suspect we as site would define them as out of scope, should we be formally asked.

So yes questions about ant farms are on topic at pets, the specific question you reference at biology would most likely be out of scope.

**Follow up**

I posted the question [Are there native web building spiders in North America that can be domesticated?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/5919) which tests several scope issues; as it addresses the domestication of a native insect.  It did not get a lot of support or negative attention.  So barring some change, both insect pets and domestication of wild species would seem to be in scope.

Comment: I agree with a bit of a caveat, I think domestication may be on topic if the animal is being domesticated as a pet rather than for food production.

Comment: It's worth bearing in mind that many kinds of fish and exotic pets are wild-caught. They often have their own husbandry issues -- rejection of prepared foods, heavy parasite loads, and so on. Regardless of whether the OP is also the animal's original collector, I think questions around them should probably be on-topic.

Comment: Also, I imagine that questions on keeping feeder insects for reptiles/amphibians/arachnids would be on topic, and it would seem strange to allow questions about a colony of crickets, say, but disallow questions about a colony of ants.

Comment: @starsplusplus We have [Is it possible to breed crickets for food?](http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/1932/) But there is thin line on the border of farming and raising pets, as an example a question that asked about raising dogs/cats/rabbits to feed to a pet lion or alligator, would likely be considered out of scope.

Comment: @JamesJenkins But gut-loading crickets (or other insects) is an essential part of caring for your reptile (see my answer [here](http://pets.stackexchange.com/a/2024/628)) so is actually part of the care of the reptile itself. And if you feed live food, you also need to know how to not kill it before your pet gets to eat it, so I think that would come under caring for your pet too.

Comment: [New question](http://meta.pets.stackexchange.com/q/1863/481)! @starsplusplus

Comment: Thanks, @MattS.